# Unable to run DB2 scripts using ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, db2, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

Created script file `script.sh` which consists of the command

```
db2 connect to <DB Name>
```

The above shell script is saved in the remote server and I am trying to run this script via `ansible-playbook`  which is available locally on my laptop mentioned below:

```
- hosts: node2
  tasks:
  - name: change current directory and execute command
    register: result
    become: true
    become_method: su
    become_user: db2inst1
    changed_when: true
    shell:
      chdir: /data/db2script/
      cmd : ./script.sh
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"
```

with inventory file `inventory`

```
[remote]    # group name
node1 ansible_host=<IP Address> ansible_ssh_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=<password>
node2 ansible_host=<IP Address> ansible_ssh_user=db2inst1 ansible_ssh_pass=<password>
```

while running command `ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml`

getting below error:

> fatal: [node2]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "db2 connect ", "delta": "0:00:00.004647", "end": "2023-09-29 03:32:53.888841", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2023-09-29 03:32:53.884194", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: db2: not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: 1: db2: not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

suggestions will be helpful

Comment: *sh* can't find *db2* `"/bin/sh: 1: db2: not found"`. The easiest remedy is putting the full path to *db2* into the script.

Comment: As mentioned, tried db2 full path but still getting error below:

```
fatal: [node2]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/bin/db2 connect <DB Name>", "delta": "0:00:00.041848", "end": "2023-09-29 06:13:49.806054", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 8, "start": "2023-09-29 06:13:49.764206", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "SQL10007N Message \"-1390\" could not be retrieved.  Reason code: \"3\".", "stdout_lines": ["SQL10007N Message \"-1390\" could not be retrieved.  Reason code: \"3\"."]}
```

Comment: Test the command without Ansible first. Then try Ansible. Make sure the same user is running the command. See [Become connection variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html#become-connection-variables).

Comment: Inside the `script.sh` , do you dot in (or otherwise ensure the execution of) the correct db2profile (before invoking the `db2` commands) ?  That is essential to setup all the required variables. You should also arrange that the authid (i.e. the account name) that runs the script has directly (or indirectly) the relevant authorities on the database.

Comment: Can you please some example which can be helpful, tried same as mentioned above, remotely I am able to run but when I try with ansible playbook, missing permissions, and db2profile is not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally It worked out for me using below:

```
- name: Connect to DB 
    become: true
    become_method: sudo
    become_user: db2inst1
    become_flags: 'su - db2inst1 /bin/bash -c'
    register: result
    shell:
      cmd : ./script.sh
- debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"
```